# Reasons behind Soviets Using Prolog Programming Language for Buran Space Shuttle?

Tags: software, buran

I was reading a [post](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19006/what-operating-systems-were-used-in-the-space-shuttle) related to the operating system of American Space Shuttles, then wondered what might Soviets have used. I found a CIA [document](https://web.archive.org/web/20120611225718/http://www.foia.cia.gov/docs/DOC_0000498691/DOC_0000498691.pdf) and several forums saying that Prolog was used in the Buran. I have experience in object oriented and a decent understanding of logic programming languages but I can't find a reason why they might have chosen such a complicated way of developing a system.

Comment: Obligatory video of Bald & Bankrupt [breaking in to see the Buran](https://youtu.be/0fZ-r5Qe3tM) and causing an international incident 

Comment: Prolog would be an incredibly odd - and I might say impossible - choice of programming language for a realtime system like controlling a space plane - even moreso in the period of Shuttle and Buran development. Prolog is a language for expressing pure logic and is used in AI, pattern matching, etc. I don't even know if it can do this kind of realtime command and control task - in that era doing things like tight memory and performance control, interfacing to specialized hardware, etc would likely make the choice C, or even assembly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_programme) the use of prolog is just a mistake in the CIA report:

> Researchers at Keldysh developed two languages: PROL2 (used for real-time programming of onboard systems) and DIPOL (used for the ground-based test systems), as well as the development and debugging environment SAPO PROLOGUE
>
> ...
>
> A declassified May 1990 CIA report citing open-source intelligence material states that the software for the Buran spacecraft was written in "the French-developed programming language known as Prolog", possibly due to confusion with the name PROLOGUE.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. I was very confused upon reading the OP's question why they would choose Prolog over Refal, which is a language designed in the USSR that would give most of the same benefits that you would get from Prolog. So, it turns out, they used neither :-D

Comment: The "virgin" Mary of the space age...