# Interplanetary spacecraft flight operating system and programming language

Tags: the-moon, interplanetary, software, flight-computer

Which programming languages and operating systems are mostly used for interplanetary satellites (such as a mission to the moon)?

To my knowledge, I know some LEO CubeSats use C programming language with the FREERTOS system. Is it the same for interplanetary mission or something else is used to handle more complex tasks?

Comment: Ada and C/C++ are the most common programming languages, I believe. Operating systems are more varied, with some probes not using an OS at all (embedded systems). VxWorks has been used in a number of NASA applications. The ESA's Rosetta used Virtuoso RTOS. That makes the operating system portion of this question kind of hard to pin down. Maybe you could explain a little more why you want to know so we can narrow the field down a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filo has covered operating systems, so I won't repeat that here (except to reference [this answer about New Horizons' OS](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/9820/29766), which is [Nucleus RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleus_RTOS) rather than VxWorks, by way of a change).

As for programming languages, there's inevitably a lot of C and C++, though there's a chance that a somewhat restricted subset of the languages is used to improve safety, ease of reasoning about programs, realtime response limits and memory usage and all the rest so they won't quite be the usual C and C++.

For some examples of stuff that *isn't* C, how about:

- [HAL/S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL/S), originally designed for the Space Shuttle (aparently 85% of shuttle software was written in it). It has been used for other things, such as [Galileo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_(spacecraft)), which was put together back when the shuttle was still a thing.
- Assembly language is common, especially for older projects where there would have been much poorer support for high level languages. The [Apollo 11 AGC source code](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11) is open source if you wanted to see what it looked like.
- [FORTRAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) seems to be everywhere. [Voyager](https://www.wired.com/2013/09/vintage-voyager-probes/) used FORTRAN 5 (presumably not released in 1905, but sometimes I do wonder... certainly it predated lower case letters) and later Fortran 77, also some C and some assembly language.
- [Ada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)) has appeared in [many projects](https://www2.seas.gwu.edu/~mfeldman/ada-project-summary.html#Scientific_Space_Vehicles_), including [Huygens](https://sci.esa.int/web/cassini-huygens/?fareaid=12), [Mars Express](https://sci.esa.int/web/mars-express) and [Rosetta](https://sci.esa.int/web/rosetta/).
- [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)) [is also used](https://www.forth.com/resources/space-applications/) (in [NEAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEAR_Shoemaker), Galileo, Cassini, Rosetta and others), though more for smaller subcomponents and sensors rather than bigger and fancier control systems, I think. It is a quite different language to all the others listed here.
- There's stuff that [transpiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) to C, such as [Simulink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulink). This [was apparently used](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/3d9luh/were_scientists_on_the_nasa_new_horizons_team/) for the guidance and control stuff in [New Horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons), though the vast majority of the rest of the software on the probe was written directly in C.

I don't doubt there are many others, but this seems to take care of the vast majority of things.

Comment: 1905? That's an old probe! :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#Fortran_5

Comment: @called2voyage not to be confused with fortran V, of course.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Exactly, simple stuff. :P

Comment: I know that Lisp was used on the ground, but I am pretty sure I also heard about it being used on at least one spacecraft.

Comment: @JörgWMittag it is possible, but unlikely... the memory allocation magic, for example, doesn't necessarily play well with the sort of predictability people like for safety or real-time critical software. You can work around it, but it is a massive faff.

Answer (score 3):

Example 1 : RTEMS, source https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/TBR/Website/Wheres_RTEMS

Example 2: VxWorks, source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VxWorks#Aerospace_and_defense